# Mutual Exclusion in an Ember ArrayController

Tags: ember.js

I have a list of items in an array controller. Clicking on an item makes it "active", but I’d like only one item to be active at any a time (akin to radio buttons).

I have this working by storing the active item in a computed property, then toggling its active state in an action on the array controller, see: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wavay/2/edit

However, this doesn’t handle the case where an item is made active by some other means i.e. *not* through the action.

I have experimented with observing the `isActive` change (using `.observesBefore('@each.isActive')`), and flipping the state of the `activeItem`, but of course, this approach causes an infinite loop.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using a combination of [`Ember.reduceComputed`](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_reduceComputed) and observers.

The `removedItem` and `addedItem` callbacks in `Ember.reduceComputed` are given access to the object which has changed, as well as `instanceMeta`, which can be used to store the “active” item:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  itemController: 'item',

  activeItem: Ember.reduceComputed('@this.@each.isActive', {

    initialValue: null,

    removedItem: function (accumulatedValue, item, changeMeta, instanceMeta) {
      if (item.get('isActive')) {
        var previousActiveItem = instanceMeta.activeItem;
        if (previousActiveItem) previousActiveItem.set('isActive', false);
        return instanceMeta.activeItem = item;
      }
      return instanceMeta.activeItem = null;
    },

    addedItem: function (accumulatedValue, item, changeMeta, instanceMeta) {
      return instanceMeta.activeItem;
    }
  })
  …
```

However if `activeItem` is not accessed anywhere, `removedItem` and `addedItem` will never be called, and therefore items will remain active until they are manually toggled. To fix this, an observer can be set up to call `this.get('activeItem')` whenever an `isActive` property is changed:

```
setActiveItem: function () {
  this.get('activeItem');
}.observes('@each.isActive')
```

See the updated jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wavay/3/edit?js,output

Related: David Hamilton’s presentation on [Array Computing Properties](http://confreaks.com/videos/3457-emberconf2014-array-computing-properties).

Comment: Any way to pre select 'Red' as the active one?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution based on your toggleActive implementation is available [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kerih/3/edit).

This solution works if the "active" flag is updated only with the toggleActive controller method. So far the controller represents the state, it makes sense that provides the api to update its data correctly.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
      itemController: 'item',

      activeItem: function() {
        return this.findBy('isActive');
      }.property('@each.isActive'),

      toggleActiveModel: function(model) {
        var controller = this.findBy('model', model);
        this._toggleActive(controller);
      },

      _toggleActive: function(controller) {
        var previouslyActive = this.get('activeItem');
        if(previouslyActive && previouslyActive !== controller) {
          previouslyActive.set('isActive', false);
        } 
        controller.set('isActive', !controller.get('isActive'));

      },

      actions: {
        toggleActive: function(controller) {
           this._toggleActive(controller); 
        },
        toggle: function(modelValue) {
           this.toggleActiveModel(modelValue); 
        }

      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, having to update the `isActive` property on the item controller via the array controller isn’t really ideal.